# How do I enlarge "Icon & Thumbnail" size in nautilus 3.x?

Tags: nautilus, 11.10, icons, thumbnails

I used to be able to set my icon/thumbnail size to 128 px using gconf-editor in previous versions of Ubuntu. Is there a tweak to enable larger icons/thumbnails in nautilus 3.x?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to install [dconf-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dconf-tools) [image: Install dconf-tools], then run `dconf-editor`

Navigate to **org > gnome > nautilus > icon-view** and set the thumbnail-size to 128.

Comment: A more detailed answer is now in https://askubuntu.com/questions/539802/nautilus-thumbnails-size-fix