# Made a huge mistake and deleted my /home/user folder (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: data-recovery

I was following this question here: [Nautilus Thumbnails Size Fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539802/nautilus-thumbnails-size-fix)

I screwed something up and I don't know how to fix it.
I installed `dconf-editor` and changed the thumbnail size in nautilus. after that was done, I entered (or at least I thought I did):

```
sudo rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails/
```

Now it looks like my user settings are gone.

My bookmarks in chromium are gone, the downloads directory is empty, and I know there were some files in there with some TV show episodes in them.

I looked in the system log and discovered that I typo'd the path as `/home/zombie /.c.cache/thumbnails/` From the system `auth.log`

```
 May 28 15:55:54 Zombie-Dell sudo:   zombie : TTY=pts/4 ; PWD=/home/zombie ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/rm -r /home/zombie /.c.cache/thumbnails/
```

Comment: First of all **immediately stop using that Ubuntu installation** and boot straight to a live DVD/USB. If you don't have one, do not download it from that PC. Go get it somewhere else. If you have a dual boot, you might also use Windows to download the ISO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Stop using that Ubuntu installation

First of all **immediately stop using that Ubuntu installation**. Now!

You should boot straight to a live DVD/USB. If you don't have one, do not download it from that system and go get it somewhere else. However, if you have a dual boot, you might also use Windows to download the ISO.

## Try to access the deleted files

When you are using the live DVD, check the partitions with:

```
sudo parted -l
```

You need to find the right one that contains your home directory. For example, my computer shows the following for drive `/dev/sda`:

```
Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  256MB  255MB  primary   ext2         boot
 2      257MB   250GB  250GB  extended
 5      257MB   250GB  250GB  logical
```

This is not the best example because I am using full disk encryption, but assuming I wanted to restore files from `/boot` I would target `/dev/sda1`  (basically look at the number).

At this point, connect an external hard drive where you want to recover the files.

Now you need to install a program called Testdisk:

```
sudo apt install testdisk
```

Then run it on your drive:

```
sudo testdisk /dev/sda
```

It will display an interactive procedure that you need to follow through the textual interface. Basically you will arrive at a list of partitions and you need to select the right one with the arrow keys.

Then you will need to press <kbd>P</kbd> to show the files and navigate in the directory tree. Once you have determined that **hopefully** your home directory contains the stuff (shown in red since it has been deleted), go one level up so that you highlight your username inside `/home` and press <kbd>C</kbd> to activate the *Copy* function.

Testdisk will ask you where you want to save the files. Navigate to a directory in your external hard drive and confirm. Wait patiently while it restores your data in the external drive.

## Bottom line

Ubuntu has [a backup program installed by default](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem). You should use it routinely, before something like this happens again.

Comment: Thanks!  I just need to find a drive big enough to copy the data on to.  I think this will solve it.