# How to recover deleted user with data in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: data-recovery, user-management

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 desktop edition. By mistake one user account deleted, which contain some data on desktop. Please help me to recover deleted data from user account or whole user account with data. I am in big trouble.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover deleted files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Made a huge mistake and deleted my /home/user folder (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/779190/made-a-huge-mistake-and-deleted-my-home-user-folder-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

### General information

There are several tools focusing on recovering deleted files. I do know:

- Testdisk
- PhotoRec

*The following is copied from the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_recovery) - which list more tools*

**TestDisk** and **Photorec** are both open-source data recovery utilities licensed under the terms of the GNU Public License (GPL).

**[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)** is primarily designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software, certain types of viruses, or human error, such as the accidental deletion of partition tables.

**[PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)** is file recovery software designed to recover lost files including photographs (Hint: PhotographRecovery), videos, documents, archives from hard disks and CD-ROMs. PhotoRec ignores the filesystem and goes after the underlying data, so it will still work even with a re-formatted or severely damaged filesystems and/or partition tables.

So - if no other input comes - check out [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) in the first step.

### Installation

To install run

```
sudo apt install testdisk
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

This should install both `photorec` and `testdisk`.

### Starting the apps

You can start them by simply entering the program-name in a terminal. So enter `photorec` or `testdisk` to start the related application.

### Recovering Step by Step

- A step by step guide for `testdisk` can be found [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).
- A step by step guide for `photorec` can be found [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step).

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer to include directions on *how* to do the recovery? As it currently is, it looks like a software recommendations list.