# Copy Only one directory (recursively) from a damaged NTFS drive

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs

I am an Ubuntu user and I have a friend with a busted NTFS drive. I know about safecopy, which can copy a file, or clone a whole partition to an image, skipping errors.

However, I did this, and I can't mount the image because it's too damaged. In any case, there's way more there than I need to recover. I only need one folder with a bunch of photos (and subfolders) in it.

I also know about photorec, but that was scraping tons of unneeded image files off this huge drive and it estimated over 200 hours to complete.

So really, I just need to copy the one directory, quickly skipping errors. If some images can't be copied, I'll cut my losses.

Comment: The problem is the "quickly skipping error" issue - any drive based errors will seize up the process no matter how you try to do it.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/791684/271

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be the best solution:

cp -Rfv source target

-R: recurse through subfolders
-f: skip over undreadable files
-v: verbose output so you can see what was skipped.