# 18.04 file manager preview thumbnail size

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, filemanager, thumbnails

Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Trying to figure out if I can adjust thumbnail size of previews in the file manager.
Right now with the Pictures folder open, I have 7 rows of 11 files each. I'd like to have those thumbnails larger.
Anybody?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nautilus: Show image thumbnails at more than 200% size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097934/nautilus-show-image-thumbnails-at-more-than-200-size)

Comment: And: https://askubuntu.com/questions/539802/nautilus-thumbnails-size-fix

Answer (score 1):

Try going into the folder that contains the pictures, then zoom in (CTRL + Scroll Wheel). This will hopefully enlargen the files’ thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a "Scroll Wheel" (Magic Mouse blues) and I had this same question on 22.04:

You can also use (CTRL + Shift + '+') to increase size of thumbnails.