# there a way or setting for better and bigger thumbnails in the file manager? especially when not showing

Tags: filemanager, thumbnails

is there a way in ubuntu 20.10 to see bigger and or better thumbnails of pictures in the file manager? Especially if your're uploading pictures as a photographer.

[image]

in the picture you'll see what I mean. its to small and when I choose a picture, no thumbnails appear on the right. sometimes they do, but its a struggle. you have to go back and check the file name to make sure its correct.

Comment: Could you clarify in which context are these thumbnails so small? In the web-browser?

Comment: Regarding that some of the thumbnails don't show up: it's because they are bigger in file size than what is configured as maximum "thumbnailable" size. But that can be changed: In Ubuntu 20.04, In a Nautilus (file manager) window > Hamburger menu button > Preferences > "Search & Preview" tab > Thumbnails section > "Only for files smaller than" and then you can give however large value you want.

Comment: thanks, i'll try that. To answer "Levente", this happens in a browser and also in just using the file manager

Comment: just in case you want very big thumbnails, you might be interested in this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300390/larger-thumbnails-for-pictures-in-nautilus/1459134#1459134

Answer (score 1):

Since this was never answered and I had this question on 22.04 recently:

If you are not seeing thumbnails - ensure your preferences have them enabled.

If the thumbnails are too small within the file manager, you can use:

(CTRL + Shift + '+') to increase size of thumbnails.
(CTRL + 'Scroll Wheel') might work too - according to this other post: [18.04 file manager preview thumbnail size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111172/18-04-file-manager-preview-thumbnail-size/1457131#1457131)

There is an upper bound to how large you can make them, but it made them large enough for me so I didn't have to open them to know what they were a picture of.