# Set Nautilus Image Thumbnail Size in 19.10

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 19.10

In 18.04 I could set the size of thumbnails in Nautilus by adjusting the dconf setting `org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view thumbnail-size` as mentioned in
https://askubuntu.com/a/1097952/680632 
and
https://askubuntu.com/a/539812/680632

I recently upgraded to 19.10 and the `thumbnail-size` key seems to be gone. Am I missing something or is there a new way to set the thumbnail size?

Comment: Indeed, I confirm: the option is not anymore there.

Comment: I haven't found any other way to change the max thumbnail size in nautilus (3.36.3). I have also tried gthumb and thunar as alternatives for convenient photo browsing, but no luck there either.

Answer (score -2):

If you're trying to resize thumbnails for simply press the down arrow key and enter the percentage you need. The default is 50% but can be adjusted to either 67%, 100% or 133%.

I know you didn't ask, as you probably already know this , if NO or only SOME thumbnails appear go to home/.cache/thumbnails and delete everything in that folder. Then reboot and they will then appear.

Comment: The question refers to the maximum possible size of the thumbnails in the nautilus, which could have been changed through dconf in the previous version.